# How to prevent duplicate calendar events from Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm very new to this! I can trying to move the information from google sheets over to google calendar *automatically*. Unfortunately, when I run the script there are duplication on the events. Please help!

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarid");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 2);

  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
    communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[4], entry[0], entry[1]);
  });  
}
```

I am hoping to remove the duplication.

Also, if there is a way to add additional description.
For some reason, I cannot add an extra entry without it bugging. For example, I want to add location but the entry will not let me.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Also, if there is a way to add additional description. For some reason, I cannot add an extra entry without it bugging. For example, I want to add location but the entry will not let me.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: I want to add a description to the calendar invitation from my spreadsheet. Right not the calendar invitation is "Title" "Start TIme" "End Time". I want to also add "Description" but it will only let me add 3 items not 4. I hope this make sense. Sorry my english is not that great.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am still getting duplication. For example, my start date is 1/14/2023 by end date is 1/16/2023. I am getting 3 duplication because of this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `(1) I want to create a script that transfer the [title], [location], [start date], and [end date] over to the calendar.`, from your reply, you said `I want to add a description to the calendar invitation from my spreadsheet.`.  About `[2] While trying to create a scripp, if it is more than two days the event duplicate, which I'm not sure why.` and `[3] All I want is to transfer Column A [Start Date], Column B [End Date], Column C&D [Location], Column E [Title] over to the main calendar.`, I cannot understand your current situation.

Comment: From this situation, I think that I cannot still correctly understand your question. So, in this case, I have to delete my answer. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.